# ffprobe show_frames for multiple videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffprobe

Is there any way that I can see frames for multiple videos at same time in one file?

I know how to do that for one video -

> ffprobe -show_frames http://myvirtualdirectory/myvideo.mp4 > output.txt

I have so many videos in my virtual directory - so I want to see all the videos frames at one file.

And is there any way that I can see frames from my local directory - and not from virtual directory like (http://.... )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Learn to use shell scripts.

Identify your local directory and make a simple script to append (`>>`) to the output file:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /path/to/files/*.mp4; do
  ffprobe -show_frames $file >> output.txt
done
```

Make the script executable using `chmod +x show_frames.sh` and run it with `./show_frames.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am new to this so really not sure how do I make script executable using chomd +x show_frames.sh ? 

Will really appreciate if you could explain step by step. I am using Ubuntu. 

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here's a very basic step by step tutorial: http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

Comment: Oh my God - Thanks Million aergistal - It totally worked for me - I spent so many days on this. Just a little problem - As I have so many videos in folder and your suggested command make one output.txt file - Is it possible in scripting to create individual file for each video in the folder?

Comment: Just replace the command with `ffprobe -show_frames $file > ${file}.txt`. It will create a file for each mp4, like `some_video.mp4.txt`.

Comment: Yes certainly I will do - but where is that option to mark as solved ?

Comment: You click on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Dear aergistal,
Once again I really appreciate your help - it was alot to me. 
I am running this statement in shell; 
for file in /path/to/files/*.mp4; do
  ffprobe -show_frames $file | grep "data" > ${file}.txt

It would be great if I could get this information too; 

a)When I grep data row with numbers then I want script to  - divide that data numbers with 100, 
b) then calculate(sum) data row number every after 50 rows.