# ffprobe | ShowFrames | Packet Size | Divide | Add

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, grep, ffprobe

I am running this statement in shell

```
for file in /path/to/files/*.mp4; do ffprobe -show_frames $file | grep "pkt_size" > ${file}.txt
```

done

It would be great if I could get this information too;

1. When I grep pkt_size row with numbers then I want script to - divide
   every pkt_size number with 100,
2. then add (sum) pkt_size row numbers every after 50 rows.

Comment: 1. There is no `done` at the end of `for` loop. 2. Use correct formatting for source code.

Comment: There is no "data" filed in -show_frames output. Which field do you want to grep? If you can explain what exactly you want to do then may be can suggest different approach.

Comment: well greping the data was an example - I have edited the script again. 
1) Search all the mp4s in the folder, 
2) Do ffprobe -show_frames
3) Create individual output file for every video in the folder
4) Take the "pkt_size" row from the output
5) Add(sum) pkt_size numbers after every 50 rows (set of 50 rows) 
6) finally, divide by 1000 with every sum(step 5)

Comment: No need for `grep`: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries frame=pkt_size -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4`

Comment: Lord could you explain little bit pls. Just don't understand how it's adding 50 rows  and then diving ..?

Answer (score 1):

I already showed you in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988898/ffprobe-show-frames-for-multiple-videos/30000851#30000851) how to iterate all files and append results. This is how you would go about calculating stuff in `bash` for *one* file, using **@LordNeckbeard**'s `ffprobe` command.

Your homework is to modify and integrate the two answers.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/path/to/file.mp4

if [ ! -f $file ]; then
    echo Error: File not found
    exit 1
fi

pkt_sizes=$(ffprobe -show_entries frame=pkt_size -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -i $file -loglevel 0)

function print_sum {
    #use `bc` for floating point operations 
    sum=$(echo "scale=${precision};${sum}/100" | bc -l)
    echo "SUM("$start","$i")="$sum
}

i=1
start=1
sum=0
precision=3

#compute/print sum every 50 packets
for size in $pkt_sizes; do  
    (( sum+= size ))

    if (( $i % 50 == 0 )); then     
        print_sum
        sum=0
        start=$(( i + 1 ))
    fi 

    (( i++ ))   
done;

#sum last packets (n < 50)
if (( "$start" < "$i" )); then  
    (( i-- ))
    print_sum
fi
```

This is more than enough to get you started with shell arithmetic so please refer to the documentation for further questions.

Comment: Hi Aergistal, 
Many thanks for your efforts. Really appreciate it. I am really new to this shell programming. That's please ignore my silly questions.  
I saved your code with correct path/to/file/file.mp4
But this is what happenning, Ben@ben-VirtualBox  ~/Downlaods $ which bash
/bin/bash
Ben@ben-VirtualBox  ~/Downlaods $ chmod +x script.sh
Command not found
Ben@ben-VirtualBox  ~/Downlaods $ script.sh
Command not found

Comment: Please guide for execution this particular file.